# How to push to another working copy with ability to commit from it

Tags: git

This is behavior I want to replicate with GIT:

I have 3 Developers and 1 Production server.

Production server has GIT repo in `/srv/proj1` and it is on commit `#10`

Developers push changes to `/srv/proj1` and I do `git co master`.

I can commit my changes in `/srv/proj1`.

Developers can pull changes from `/srv/proj1/`.

**But** I heard that GIT can't do this(it gives strange errors) and I should create `--bare` repo and then clone it or checkout. But I lose ability to commit porssible hot-fix changes.

Do I do something wrong? Is it possible?

Comment: You can still commit hotfixes and push them. What is stoping you from that?

Comment: @Zeeker I don't want to push them. I want to commit hotfixes on the production, instead of commiting it somewhere else and pushing to production. I know it is not a good way, but I prefer it for one project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git by default doesn't allow anyone to push to the currently checked out branch of a repo.
If you are on the production server checked out to master trying to make a hot-fix, and the developers are trying to push changes to master they will get the below output.  There are ways to work around it as described in the error output, but the typical thing to do would be to use a bare repo for production, then use a separate repo to commit/push hotfixes from.

`(master)$ git push
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 262 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
remote: error: 
remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to
remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing into
remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless you
remote: error: arranged to update its work tree to match what you pushed in some
remote: error: other way.
remote: error: 
remote: error: To squelch this message and still keep the default behaviour, set
remote: error: 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable to 'refuse'.
To /scratch/r1
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (branch is currently checked out)
error: failed to push some refs to '/scratch/r1'`

Comment: This is a problem I stuck with, definitly! I can't really understand why it is a problem. With Mercurial I can push anything anywhere and it doesn't matter at which commit and branch I am. I can easily update to needed commit and it simply works... Why can't I do this with GIT? :(

Comment: You can.  Just do `git config receive.denyCurrentBranch false` on the production server and then hope for the best when you are doing hot-fixes.

Comment: Keyword is "hope". I don't wanna do it if it is a wrong way. But I don't really understand why it is so easy in Mercurial and gives so many stragne errors in GIT.

Comment: The normal way is to use a second repo.  If you really want to work directly on production then I would suggest create a pre-receive hook that prints out "LOCKED for hot-fix, try back later" and exits 1, and just enable that whenever you are hot-fixing and disable it when you are done.

Comment: But when should I unlock it, when I commit my changes? I mean, if I have no not-committed changes, GIT will allow to push to this repo w/o this error?

Comment: LOCK repo.  Force update your working directory and index to match via git reset --hard, modify files, commit files, UNLOCK repo.

Comment: It looks ugly... why I should update index manualy and do this stuff... It is not what I expected to see in GIT. But TY, I prefer way of bare repo.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to see where you heard git cant do this. Git was designed to be distributed, not hosted. What this means is that any git repository can act as a remote. The only reason "git servers" exist is because that is the model we are usually most accustomed too.

There should be nothing wrong with what you have proposed. Git handles it just fine.

When you "push" to a remote, it is essentially the exact same thing as a commit, because a push just takes your commits and adds them to the remote.

However, strange behaviour COULD occur if someone pushed code while you were working on it.

Example, Developers push changes. You checkout. You are working on some stuff, and now Developers push again. The developer will now get a bunch of errors because the branch is checked out. They cannot push (or pull) again until you commit and checkout HEAD.
You could resolve this by making a new branch, making the changes, then merging the changes back into master.

In regards to hotfixes, you could always just submit a hotfix using a push. You do not have to work on the server directly.

Comment: Ty, gonna check it a bit later. I had problems when I was trying to push something to empty remote (with just `git init`), strange errors, Internets was suggesting to use `--bare` and separated repo. I'll try today it again.

Comment: Except that the developer won't be able to 'push again' because the default behavior of git is to reject any push update to the currently checked out branch and spew out 14 lines of error output

Comment: @AndrewC THIS! Maybe it is a reason shy I had error. How I can deal wih it?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I did some research and modified my answer